# Datadog - rollup a metric (aggregate) by number of events

Tags: datadog

Is it possible to rollup a metric (aggregate) by number of events instead of time (in the context of a dashboard or/and monitor)?

Context:

- I created a new metric `payment_processed` with two tags:

  - `status` (failure or success)
  - `partner_identifier` (our platform support ~80 different partners)
- on top of this metric, I created what I call the `payment_failure_rate`

  - `(count(payment_processed.status=failure) / ( count(payment_processed.status=failure) + count(payment_processed.status=success) ))`
- I would like to monitor the `payment_failure_rate` by `partner_identifier` with an anomaly detection algorithm
- Challenges:

  - the number of `payment_processed` events per day is varying a lot per partner (some can only have ~50 events in a day and others thousands)
  - the `payment_failure_rate` per partner can vary a lot (for some partner it can be “normal” to have ~20% failure rate,  but for others the normal can be ~5% failure rate)

What I tried (and failed): To smooth the data, I tried to rollup the data (by time), but this was enough

- I did not succeeded to configure a rollup time that would be efficient for all partners
- For some partner with high traffic, the rollup time that would make sense would be 1h
- And for other partners with low traffic, the rollup time that would make sense would be 2 days

Question: Would it be possible to rollup/aggregate the data by number of events instead of time?

For example, continuously  calculating the payment_failure_rate of the last 100 attempts (regardless of how many times it tooks to aggregate those)?

And even better, aggregating with a sliding window?

Thank you